# Django Ajax form not being saved

Tags: django, ajax, ajaxform

I want to use Ajax in Django to handle the view of my  checkout form after it has been submitted. After the form is submitted, I want it to go to :

`return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(str(next_page))+"?address_added=True")` , i.e http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkout/?address_added=True

But for some reason, it is not going there. Rather it's being going to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkout/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=W4iXFaxwpdtbZLyVI0ov8Uw7KWOM8Ix5GcOQ4k3Ve65KPkJwPUKyBVcE1IjL3GHa&address=123+Main+Street&address2=&state=MA&country=USA&zipcode=55525&phone=%28877%29+314-0742&billing=on`

As a result, the form data is also not getting saved. I was thinking if it were because of the new version of Django.

What I want to do is that after they submit the place order button, the form is going to be None, i.e disappear and then I would add a credit card form there for payment. But it is not happening. What is wrong here? How can I do this or is there a better way to do this?

My forms.py:

```
class UserAddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserAddress
        fields = ["address", "address", "address2", "state", "country", "zipcode", "phone", "billing"]
```

My accounts.views.py:

```
def add_user_address(request):
    try:
        next_page = request.GET.get("next")
    except:
        next_page = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserAddressForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_address = form.save(commit=False)
            new_address.user = request.user
            new_address.save()
            if next_page is not None:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(str(next_page))+"?address_added=True")
    else:
        raise Http404
```

My orders.views.py:

```
@login_required()
def checkout(request):
    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
    except:
        the_id = None
        return redirect(reverse("myshop-home"))

    try:
        new_order = Order.objects.get(cart=cart)
    except Order.DoesNotExist:
        new_order = Order(cart=cart)
        new_order.cart = cart
        new_order.user = request.user
        new_order.order_id = id_generator()
        new_order.save()
    except:
        return redirect(reverse("cart"))


    try:
        address_added = request.GET.get("address_added")
    except:
        address_added = None 

    if address_added is None:
        address_form = UserAddressForm()
    else:
        address_form = None

    if new_order.status == "Finished":
        #cart.delete()
        del request.session['cart_id']
        del request.session['items_total']
        return redirect(reverse("cart"))


    context = {"address_form": address_form, "cart": cart}
    template = "orders/checkout.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

My urls.py:

```
path('ajax/add_user_address', accounts_views.add_user_address, name='ajax_add_user_address'),
```

My checkout.html:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'ajax_add_user_address' %}?redirect=checkout">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">   
        {{ address_form|crispy }}
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit">Place Order</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This question appears in a sequence of 11 questions from the same author on the same, or nearly the same topic. Many of these are copy-paste duplicate of each other, and will serve to waste the time of helpful readers who have not checked how many times the question has been re-asked.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally split these up in two views, because they do different stuff.

But, if you want to keep it that way, you can do the following:

First of all, because you are making an AJAX Request, you should return a JsonResponse object.

In your view you can render the checkout.html and pass it as a context variable to your json response:

```
def add_user_address(request):
   ...

   data = dict()
   context = {
       'address_form': form,
       ...
   }

   data['html_form'] = render_to_string("checkout.html",
                                        context,
                                        request=request)
   return JsonResponse(data)
```

And in your `$.ajax` success function you can do the following

```
success: function(data) {
  // console.log(data);
  $("div-to-replace-html").html(data.html_form);

}
```

Comment: It did not work
Btw brother, it is splitted into two views(edit)
Now can you please say where should I add each of them?

Comment: Anyone help please?

Comment: What is not working? Where are you executing your ajax request? If you are simply posting your form, then you are not making an ajax request. Try this in your view `add_user_address` : `print("Request is ajax: ", self.request.is_ajax())`