# Django - Problems with Ajax Form

Tags: django, ajax, django-forms

I'm trying to develop an e-commerce website using Django. I want to use Ajax to handle the view of my  checkout form after it has been submitted. After the form is submitted, I want it to go to :

`return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(str(next_page))+"?address_added=True")` , i.e http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkout/?address_added=True

But for some reason, it is not going there. Rather it's being going to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkout/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=W4iXFaxwpdtbZLyVI0ov8Uw7KWOM8Ix5GcOQ4k3Ve65KPkJwPUKyBVcE1IjL3GHa&address=123+Main+Street&address2=&state=MA&country=USA&zipcode=55525&phone=%28877%29+314-0742&billing=on`

As a result, the form data is also not getting saved. I was thinking if it were because of the new version of Django.

What I want to do is that after they submit the place order button, the form is going to be None, i.e disappear and then I would add a credit card form there for payment. But it is not happening. What is wrong here? How can I do this or is there a better way to do this?

My forms.py:

```
class UserAddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserAddress
        fields = ["address", "address", "address2", "state", "country", "zipcode", "phone", "billing"]
```

My accounts.views.py:

```
def add_user_address(request):
    try:
        next_page = request.GET.get("next")
    except:
        next_page = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserAddressForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_address = form.save(commit=False)
            new_address.user = request.user
            new_address.save()
            if next_page is not None:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(str(next_page))+"?address_added=True")
    else:
        raise Http404
```

My orders.views.py:

```
@login_required()
def checkout(request):
    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
    except:
        the_id = None
        return redirect(reverse("myshop-home"))

    try:
        new_order = Order.objects.get(cart=cart)
    except Order.DoesNotExist:
        new_order = Order(cart=cart)
        new_order.cart = cart
        new_order.user = request.user
        new_order.order_id = id_generator()
        new_order.save()
    except:
        return redirect(reverse("cart"))


    try:
        address_added = request.GET.get("address_added")
    except:
        address_added = None 

    if address_added is None:
        address_form = UserAddressForm()
    else:
        address_form = None

    if new_order.status == "Finished":
        #cart.delete()
        del request.session['cart_id']
        del request.session['items_total']
        return redirect(reverse("cart"))


    context = {"address_form": address_form, "cart": cart}
    template = "orders/checkout.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

My urls.py:

```
path('ajax/add_user_address', accounts_views.add_user_address, name='ajax_add_user_address'),
```

My checkout.html:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'ajax_add_user_address' %}?redirect=checkout">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">   
        {{ address_form|crispy }}
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit">Place Order</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You can either submit an HTML-form or do an ajax call - not both in one. Ajax is used to send and receive data from the server without reloading the page. Do you really need this here? If yes, look at Ajax examples - you need to collect the data you want to submit via JS and then send them to the server.

Comment: Something like your tenth wilful and time-wasting duplicate: [Django Ajax form not being saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61286082/django-ajax-form-not-being-saved)

Comment: This question appears in a sequence of 11 questions from the same author on the same, or nearly the same topic. Many of these are copy-paste duplicate of each other, and will serve to waste the time of helpful readers who have not checked how many times the question has been re-asked.